# Jest automatically adds proptypes to snapshots?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

There's a component that just renders another component (idk why we did this):

```
class FooContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <FooView />;
  }
}
```

The test for this component is:

```
describe('<FooContainer/>', () => {
  it('renders a correct snapshot', () => {
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    const tree = renderer.render(<FooContainer />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The snapshot that another member of the team generated looks like this:

```
exports[`<FooContainer/> renders a correct snapshot 1`] = `<Connect(FooView) />`;
```

However, when I generate the snapshot, it adds properties to `FooView`:

```
exports[`<FooContainer/> renders a correct snapshot 1`] = `
<FooView
  prop={123}
/>
`;
```

These properties are in the proptypes of `FooView`, but they're not specified in the test. Did Jest automatically look at the proptypes and add them to the snapshot? How can I turn this off?

Since we're using a `yarn.lock`, we should all be using the same version of Jest. I'm using Jest 21.2.1.

Comment: Is `FooContainer` a Redux connected component? If so, is it possible that there was a change to run Jest with a default store/state which would then pass a property value to `FooContainer` that would affect `FooView`?

Comment: `FooContainer` isn't connected, but `FooView` is. I'm also wondering if there's a change, but I couldn't find any information.

Comment: If `FooView` is connected, then the only way it would not render `<Connect(FooView) />` is if you use `.dive()`. Could it be that `123` comes from the store?